# Entity Framework Code First - Relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to add relationships to my entities using EF Code First in Web API project

My Database Seed code is

```
internal class ProductDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ProductDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ProductDbContext context)
    { 
        Category category = new Category();
        LanguagesDbContext languagesDbContext = new LanguagesDbContext();
        List<Language> languages = new List<Language>
        {
            new Language {Name="English",Code="en" },
            new Language {Name="Italian", Code="it" },
            new Language {Name="Russian",Code="rus" },
        };

        languagesDbContext.Languages.AddRange(languages);

        context.Categories.Add(category);

        List<CategoryText> categoryText = new List<CategoryText>();

        foreach (var language in languages)
        {
            string name = string.Empty;

            switch (language.Code)
            {
                case "en":
                    name = "paper";
                    break;
                case "it":
                    name = "carta";
                    break;
                case "rus":
                    name = "бумага";
                    break;
                default:
                    name = "paper";
                    break;
            }

            categoryText.Add(new CategoryText
            {
                Category = category,
                Language = language,
                Name = name
            });
        }

        category.CategoryTexts.Add(categoryText[1]);
        context.CategoryTexts.AddRange(categoryText);

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

everything is stored in DB and I think problem in declaration of my classes, because when I want to get `Categories` I have not able to see `CategoryTexts`

this is output in browser

[image: output in browser]

but in database I have my `CategoryTexts` added with valid `CategoryId`.

this is my Category and CategoryText Entities

```
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        CategoryTexts = new List<CategoryText>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CategoryText> CategoryTexts { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class CategoryText
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LanguageId")]
    public Language Language { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Please help me to understand where do I need to change code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either eager load your relationships (using `Include` when you query), for example:

```
var myList = context.Products.Include("Categories").Include("CategoryTexts").ToList();
```

Or you can explicitly load them (with `context.Entry(x).[Reference|Collection](x).Load()`, for example:

```
var myProduct = context.Products.First();
context.Entry(myProduct).Collection(x => x.Categories).Load();
```

Or:

```
var myCategoryText = context.CategoryText.First();
context.Entry(myCategoryText).Reference(x => x.Language).Load();
```

Or you can have them auto-load (lazy loading) using proxies... but for that, your foreign entities and collections must be marked `virtual` in your POCOs:

```
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        CategoryTexts = new List<CategoryText>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CategoryText> CategoryTexts { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class CategoryText
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LanguageId")]
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You also need to have proxy creation and lazy loading turned on, but that's the default in EF6.

Also remember that the context must be "alive" (not disposed) when accesing the properties so that there's a live context where they can be loaded

Link to related documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: so If I mark as virtual it will be added automatically?

Comment: Yes, if you have lazy loading on and proxy generation, and the context is still available (not disposed) when accesing the reference, it'll load it

Comment: Very useful info. Could you also add `Include` example for this case?

Comment: @uteist just added examples of both eager and explicitly loading, and a link to the official EF6 documentation about loading related entities