# Returning Entity with its children

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Hi I am trying to return all vehicles with their recorded mileage through an api using ASP.Net Core with the following code:

```
// GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Vehicle> Get()
    {
        return _context.Vehicles.Include(m=>m.Mileages).ToList();
    }
```

However this only returns the first vehicle with its mileages and not the others (there are five dummy vehicles in the db all with an initial mileage).

If I change the code to:

```
// GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Vehicle> Get()
    {
        return _context.Vehicles.ToList();
    }
```

it returns the full list of vehicles but no mileage.

My class files are:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public Vehicle()
    {
        Mileages = new List<Mileage>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Registration { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public Marked Marked { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Mileage> Mileages { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Mileage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime MileageDate { get; set; }
    public string RecordedMileage { get; set; }

    //Navigation Properties
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }
    public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
}
```

thanks for looking!

Tuppers

Comment: Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38907858/entity-framework-code-first-relationships) for further details

Comment: Can't reproduce. Are you using EF Core RTM?

Comment: Are you sure if each of Vehicles have at least one Mileage in the database?

Comment: Your query looks correct. Two things to try, dont initialise Milages in the constructor, EF should do that for you. And what does your mapping look like (something of the form `HasMany(x=>x.Mileages).WithRequired(x=>x.Vehicle).HasForeignKey(x=>x.Id);`)

Answer (score 0):

you can have them auto-load (lazy loading) using proxies... but for that, your foreign entities and collections must be marked virtual in your POCOs:

```
public class Mileage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime MileageDate { get; set; }
    public string RecordedMileage { get; set; }
    //Navigation Properties
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle
{
    public Vehicle()
    {
        Mileages = new List<Mileage>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Registration { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public Marked Marked { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Mileage> Mileages { get; set; }
}
```

The proxy creation and lazy loading turned on, but that's the default in EF6.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Unfortunately LazyLoading is not has not been implemented at this time in EF Core at this time.

Comment: Lazy loading in a web request is a really bad idea anyway. Its super inefficient.

Comment: unfortunately no this did not work. I believe it has to do with my query as it is returning a self referencing loop of data.

Answer (score 0):

Well after a lot of searching I managed to find a solution. I used the following:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<VehicleDto> Get()
    {
        var query = _context.Vehicles.Select(v => new VehicleDto
            {
                Registration = v.Registration,
                Make = v.Make,
                Model = v.Model,
                Marked = v.Marked,
                Mileages = v.Mileages.Select(m => new MileageDto
                    {
                        MileageDate = m.MileageDate,
                        RecordedMileage = m.RecordedMileage
                    })
                    .ToList(),
            })
            .ToList();

        return (IEnumerable<VehicleDto>) query.AsEnumerable();
```

this doesn't seem to be the most elegant way of doing this, if anyone could offer any advice but it does return what is required.

The DTO's look like:

```
public class VehicleDto
{
    public string Registration { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public Marked Marked { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MileageDto> Mileages { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class MileageDto
{
    public DateTime MileageDate { get; set; }
    public string RecordedMileage { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for taking the time to look at this

Tuppers